# Could you please suggest a way to return a typed value depending on some lookup table of key-value pairs?

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a function which returns a value with a type that matches its key. For example:

```swift
enum StorageKeys: String {
    case PREFERENCES // corresponds Preferences
    case SCORE // corresponds to Score
}

struct Preferences {
    var language: String
    var fontSize: Int
}

struct Score {
    var lastMissionName: String
    var progress: Float
    var points: Int
}

// should return a value of the type that matches the key
func getStoredValue<T>(forKey: StorageKeys) -> T? {
    // Storage.deserialize returns Decodable or Any
    if let data = Storage.shared.getObject(forKey.rawValue) as? T {
        return data
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

// usage would be like:
let prefs = getStoredValue(forKey: .PREFERENCES)
print(prefs?.language)
```

In the given example (forgive me the horrible implementation of the idea) the problem is - how do I get `T` to be of matching type for its key? Or should I abandon this idea because of potential complexity?

Comment: Maybe KeyPath is what you want

Comment: The easy solution `let prefs: Preferences? = getStoredValue(forKey: .PREFERENCES)`

Comment: Also note that the code in your function can be simplified down to only one line, `Storage.shared.getObject(forKey.rawValue) as? T `

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini AFAIK, KeyPath gives direct access to an instance property, but I couldn't understand how to use KeyPath in this case

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, but it kinda defeats the purpose :] I can accidentally cast the return value to a wrong type, therefore I would need to remember value types for every storage key

Comment: True and while I am certainly aware that there are better solutions how can you write any usable code after the call to getStoredValue if you don’t remember what type the returned values is?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I hope IDE will suggest the type and its properties thereby speeding up the development overall

Answer (score 2):

Enums cases can't have associated type information. Instead, you can use a protocol with an associated type, which represents the type of value that key corresponds to

```
protocol StorageKey {
    associatedtype Value
    var rawValue: String { get }
}
```

The enum cases would be different conformances:

```
struct PreferencesKey: StorageKey {
    typealias Value = Preferences
    var rawValue: String { "PREFERENCES" }
}

struct ScoresKey: StorageKey {
    typealias Value = Score
    var rawValue: String { "SCORE" }
}
```

Now the function can be declared as:

```
func getStoredValue<Key: StorageKey>(forKey key: Key) -> Key.Value?
```

The callers would need to do `getStoredValue(forKey: PreferencesKey())` though, which you may find rather cumbersome. In particular, there is no auto-completion.

You can recreate the enum-like syntax in a similar way to how SwiftUI's `ButtonStyle`, `LabelStyle` etc, work. You just need to write extensions of the form `extension StorageKey where Self == SomeParticularKey`:

```
extension StorageKey where Self == PreferencesKey {
    static var preferences: PreferencesKey { .init() }
}

extension StorageKey where Self == ScoresKey {
    static var scores: ScoresKey { .init() }
}
```

Now these properties are members of `StorageKey`, you can pass [implicit member expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Implicit-Member-Expression) like `.preferences` and `.scores` into the function. You even get auto-complete suggestions from Xcode.